# SQL: How to find duplicates based on two fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, unique, unique-constraint, ora-00918

I have rows in an Oracle database table which should be unique for a combination of two fields but the unique constrain is not set up on the table so I need to find all rows which violate the constraint myself using SQL.  Unfortunately my meager SQL skills aren't up to the task.

My table has three columns which are relevant: entity_id, station_id, and obs_year. For each row the combination of station_id and obs_year should be unique, and I want to find out if there are rows which violate this by flushing them out with an SQL query.

I have tried the following SQL (suggested by [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748542/how-to-find-duplicate-field-combo)) but it doesn't work for me (I get ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined):

```
SELECT
entity_id, station_id, obs_year
FROM
mytable t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT entity_id, station_id, obs_year FROM mytable 
GROUP BY entity_id, station_id, obs_year HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dupes 
ON 
t1.station_id = dupes.station_id AND
t1.obs_year = dupes.obs_year
```

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong, and/or how to solve this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY station_id, obs_year ORDER BY entity_id) AS rn
        FROM    mytable t
        )
WHERE   rn > 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response.  Unfortunately when I run this I get an "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" message.

Comment: In mssql in had to put a `as x` (name doesn't really matter) behind the FROM ( ) paranthesis to make it work. Great answer!

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT entity_id, station_id, obs_year
FROM mytable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from mytable t2 Where
       t1.station_id = t2.station_id
       AND t1.obs_year = t2.obs_year
       AND t1.RowId <> t2.RowId)
```

Comment: Looks like we cannot do this on a view:

ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table

Answer (score 2):

Re-write of your query

```
SELECT
t1.entity_id, t1.station_id, t1.obs_year
FROM
mytable t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT entity_id, station_id, obs_year FROM mytable 
GROUP BY entity_id, station_id, obs_year HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dupes 
ON 
t1.station_id = dupes.station_id AND
t1.obs_year = dupes.obs_year
```

I think the ambiguous column error (ORA-00918) was because you were `select`ing columns whose names appeared in both the table and the subquery, but you did not specifiy if you wanted it from `dupes` or from `mytable` (aliased as `t1`).

Answer (score 2):

Change the 3 fields in the initial select to be

```
SELECT
t1.entity_id, t1.station_id, t1.obs_year
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought a lot of the solutions here were cumbersome and tough to understand since I had a 3 column primary key constraint and needed to find the duplicates. So here's an option

```
SELECT id, name, value, COUNT(*) FROM db_name.table_name
GROUP BY id, name, value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not create a new table that includes the unique constraint, and then copy across the data row by row, ignoring failures?

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, thanks!

BTW I'm trying to figure out how to create the constraint on my table using annotations in my entity class (I'm a Java developer using JPA/Hibernate), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504477/how-to-specify-that-a-combination-of-columns-should-be-a-unique-constraint-using

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the table for the columns in the main select. Also, assuming entity_id is the unique key for mytable and is irrelevant to finding duplicates, you should not be grouping on it in the dupes subquery.

Try:

```
SELECT t1.entity_id, t1.station_id, t1.obs_year
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT station_id, obs_year FROM mytable 
GROUP BY station_id, obs_year HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dupes 
ON 
t1.station_id = dupes.station_id AND
t1.obs_year = dupes.obs_year
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark, for the tip about not using entity_id in the grouping subquery, and for the illustrative example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY station_id, obs_year ORDER BY entity_id) AS rn
        FROM    mytable t
        )
WHERE   rn > 1
```

by Quassnoi is the most efficient for large tables. 
I had this analysis of cost :

```
SELECT a.dist_code, a.book_date, a.book_no
FROM trn_refil_book a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from trn_refil_book b Where
       a.dist_code = b.dist_code and a.book_date = b.book_date and a.book_no = b.book_no
       AND a.RowId <> b.RowId)
       ;
```

gave a cost of 1322341

```
SELECT a.dist_code, a.book_date, a.book_no
FROM trn_refil_book a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT b.dist_code, b.book_date, b.book_no FROM trn_refil_book b 
GROUP BY b.dist_code, b.book_date, b.book_no HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) c 
ON 
 a.dist_code = c.dist_code and a.book_date = c.book_date and a.book_no = c.book_no
;
```

gave a cost of 1271699

while

```
SELECT  dist_code, book_date, book_no
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.dist_code, t.book_date, t.book_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.book_date, t.book_no
          ORDER BY t.dist_code) AS rn
        FROM    trn_refil_book t
        ) p
WHERE   p.rn > 1
;
```

gave a cost of **1021984**

The table was not indexed....

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT entity_id, station_id, obs_year
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY entity_id, station_id, obs_year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Specify the fields to find duplicates on both the SELECT and the GROUP BY.

It works by using `GROUP BY` to find any rows that match any other rows based on the specified Columns. 
The `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` says that we are only interested in seeing any rows that occur more than 1 time (and are therefore duplicates)

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Thanks Taryn. It works by using GROUP BY to find any rows that match any other rows based on the specified Columns. The HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 says that we are only interested in seeing any rows that occur more than 1 time (and are therefore duplicates)

Comment: Hi, don't tell me (in the comments). I know SQL, I'm not asking for me... This sort of explanation is "part of your complete answer"... so please edit your answer and add it there. :)

Comment: Isn't this only part of the answer? I mean, you get to know which `entity_id, station_id, obs_year` tuples have duplicates, but you don't get the actual rows which are duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised there aren't any answers here that use a CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER(
     PARTITION BY Last_Name, First_Name order by BIRTHDATE)
        AS RN,
     Employee_number, First_Name, Last_Name, BirthDate,
     SUM(1)
     OVER(
     PARTITION BY Last_Name, First_Name
     ORDER BY BIRTHDATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                             AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
         AS CNT
    FROM
        employment)
   select * from cte where cnt > 1
```

Not only will this find duplicates (on first and last name only), it will tell you how many there are.